# ndsconfig add option failed during instance creation with error code 78

Tags: ldap

if we are trying to add new tree test1.sso.com in sever 1.1.1.1 then the edirectory is trying to connect to another server tree 1.1.1.2 which has tree test2.sso.com but i am not getting in which case the edirectory will try to connect to the other server in the same segment.

steps :
1. create tree test2.sso.com in 1.1.1.1 and 1.1.1.2
2. delete the tree test2.soo.som from 1.1.1.1
3. try to add tre test1.sso.com in 1.1.1.1 then this problem is happening in linux server

Please help me to understand in which case this problem will happen

Comment: I do not follow. What commands are you running?

Comment: ndsconfig add -t ROOT -n org -a cn=something.dc=sso.dc=com -S "STANDBY" -D /opt/test/eDirectory/ssoinstance0 -d /opt/test/eDirectory/ssoinstance0/data/dib -w "password" -L 31046 -l 31047 -p $SERVERIP:$NCPPORT --config-file /opt/test/eDirectory/ssoinstance0.conf